# angular 8 routing not redirectly to correct page

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 8.
Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
Here is my app.routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LabViewerComponent } from './lab-viewer/lab-viewer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'LabViewerPDF', component: LabViewerComponent}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my home.component.html:

```
Home
<a  (click)="selectLab()">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is my app.component.html:

```
app component
<a  (click)="selectLab()">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Not sure why this url:
http://localhost:4200/#/home

Shows:
app component Click here to download my Plan (PDF)Home Click here to download my Plan (PDF)

It should be:
home component Click here to download my Plan (PDF)Home Click here to download my Plan (PDF)

Comment: you have a # in your URL because of {useHash: true},  could you please specify the pb ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AppComponent`, containing the root router outlet, is shown:

```
app component
<a  (click)="selectLab()">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When you navigate to `home`, the router outlet is filled with `HomeComponent` (and the rest is left intact), as ordered, so you get:

```
<a  (click)="selectLab()">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>

<!-- main router outlet's contents here: -->
Home
<a (click)="selectLab()">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>
<!-- this router outlet will be filled, if `home` has any child routes -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

contains the current route. You want to load home into that router outlet by clicking on a routerlink somwhere. Im suspecting this is what you mean to happen.

```
Home
<a  (click)="selectLab()">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>
```

```
app component
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```